# Best user friendly phone number format

Tags: readability, phone-numbers

What is the best way to write a phone number? Are there any studies in this regard?

I personally consider two factors:

**Country code:**

```
+393401234xxx
```

or

```
00393401234xxx
```

The first example I think is more legible, but perhaps not understandable for those who do not have the proper familiarity with the phone.

**Spacing:**

```
+393401234xxx
```

or

```
+39 340 12 34 xxx
```

I personally use spacing every 2-3 digits because I think it is more readable, especially for dyslexics. But I'm not sure the best way.

Comment: What country is this in?  The current American standards are 555-1212 and 1(800) 555-1212.  The American standard [used to be JK5-1212](http://mentalfloss.com/article/61116/why-did-old-phone-numbers-start-letters).

Comment: 0039 is Italian country code. But it is just an example.  In some country, like switzerland, if you write International code you must omit first zero: +41 (0) 123 45 678

Comment: The [American phone numbering system](http://explodingthephone.com/hoppdocs/nond1955.pdf) was developed in the mid-1950s, when an average of 7 million (long-distance) toll calls were made per day.  The 55x-xxxx numbers were reserved for "radiotelephone".  If they had been used, KLaxon 5-1212 would have been a plausible mnemonic/format.

Comment: No matter what solution you pick, just make sure it's not too region-specific. A little bit of me dies inside every time I see an Australian mobile number formatted as (04x) xxx-xxxx

Comment: Are you asking about displaying phone numbers? Or about users typing phone numbers into a field?

Comment: Do you really need a telephone number? There's research that suggests [asking for the number will hurt contact form submission rates](https://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/6748/3-Form-Fields-That-Kill-Landing-Page-Conversion-Rates.aspx#sm.00001nclwkk118enfu3sdsj7knfvk)

Comment: It sounds like you're not even sure about number dialing. It's not just switzerland where you omit the zero. If you use *any* international dialing code 00XX / 00X then you omit the first zero. e.g. a local Belgian mobile number is 0491 XXX XXX, international Belgian number is 0032 491 XXX XXX.

Comment: @icc97 It's certainly *common* to drop a 0, but not *universal*. As an obvious example, North America has no 0 to drop (arguably, you drop the 1 off the beginning, then add 1 as the international code). Note that using `00` as the prefix to dial *out* is also not universal, which is why universal formats begin with `+`.

Comment: Note that some programs auto-link phone numbers in text if they are in the [tel: link format](https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-telephone-links/).

Comment: Microsoft has a big list of phone number formats recognized by IE11 grouped by country, perhaps you could find something interesting there: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn454587(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ask yourself why you feel the need to change the format that the user as used? Whether they enter +353 86 123 4567 or 00353861234567 or, sin of sins, 086-123-4567, why not accept that they have already used the format they are most comfortable with.

Comment: 0118 999 881 99 9119 7253 - sorry, couldn't resist.

Comment: Likewise Dutch numbers are `+31 (0)6 12345678` for cellphones and `+31 (0)123 123456` for local numbers, where `(0)123` is the region. Don't try to make a global solution, just add specific formats for specific countries.

Comment: It's worth pointing out here that not all international dial codes are `00`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree that this is not only country dependent, but also region dependant.

Local numbers can have different lengths. And this separation should make clear where the local number starts.

So the first way to decide is how the local number, by local people is used.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers

---

But a more general approach would be 4 digit groupings (look at a credit card, and see how easy is to say out loud those numbers)

One unscientific rule I use is that this grouping should leave the last digits as a group of four. Otherwise, that leaves the sensation that one number is missing.

- 555 5656
- 5555 656

*Based on Michael Kjörling comment, on a 5 digit local number, the sensation of a number missing:

- 555 56 vs
- 55 556

But again, this can be override by the rule 1, the usage by local people.

---

Another non written rule is if the number is catchy.

For example a 1-800 number. Normally you group that series of numbers really fast and leave the rest to be grouped as you can.

A 1-800 then is grouped:

- 1-800-123-4567 and not
- 1-80-0123-4567

If you have a number like this:

- xx123456

You probably want to emphasize the sequence, the rhythm, so you probably can

- xx-123-456 and not
- xx12-3456

So you need to combine this "rules".

I remember some old TV campaigns that the number was a Jingle.

Comment: +1 for leaving catchy parts of a number intact (this also goes for repetitions). Additionally, I would consider even larger groupings than four digits, as in @DPS's answer.

Comment: In Germany we group by "area distance" so like +49 (xxx) yyyyyyy - zzz and leave out the +49 part if it is definetly not in an international context, often the () is left out and spaces are only used. xxx is the area code and quite important if you want to judge the costs of the call (not that important anymore since nationwide calls cost the same these days, but calls to mobile phones still cost more). The -zzz part is usually not part of the official number but the switchboard, so you know that replacing that with a 0 will almost certainly get you to a central point.

Comment: *"One unscientific rule I use is that this grouping should leave the last digits as a group of four."* My home landline phone number is +46 (for Sweden) followed by a three- or four-digit area code (depending on whether you count the initial 0), followed by a five-digit local number. Your format would cause this to become something like `+46 (0)123 4 5678`. I'm not sure that's particularly readable. The official grouping is 4+3+2 `+46 (0)123 456 78` but I personally prefer to group it 4+2+3 `+46 (0)123 45 678` because of the value of the last group when written that way.

Comment: The "principle" is simmilar. Leaving the long number last. I'll edit that.

Comment: "One unscientific rule I use is that this grouping should leave the last digits as a group of four." This answer is very North America-centric. There is a [wide variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers) of formats used around the world. Don't make one up and force people to use it.

Comment: Did you read "So the first way to decide is how the local number, by local people is used"? But I will steal your link n_n

Comment: what's song format? they played the DFMT tones?

Comment: I changed that for Jingle.

Comment: A UK company with an owl-based logo had an 800 number ending 28 28 20 (say it "two eight, two eight, two O).  It wouldn't have worked as 282 820.

Comment: Yes, in that case use the "catchy" rule.

Comment: -1, listing a bunch of formats off the top of your head that will just annoy people in lots of parts of the world is not really helpful...

Answer (score 106):

[Libraries exist to do this](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber). For spacing, I feel very strongly that the spacing expected by the user is the spacing you should use.

Most people remember phone numbers (especially their own) with a kind of rhythm based on (usually) the official spacing used in their region. When they see their number in a spacing other than that which they expect, they might not immediately recognise it as their own phone number, and become confused. It will also be harder to remember and/or recognise other people's phone numbers.

Where parts of a phone number are also optionally omitted (eg an area code if you're in the same area), using the official spacing is also important to help people quickly identify the part they can omit when dialling.

So, please, for spacing, use a library to show the numbers in the format which the user expects.

Comment: This is a massively underrated answer -- familiarity is a big deal.  In addition trying to force one country's format into another can lead to issues

Comment: And the form the user expects is what they use which is not what experts say should be used - e.g. London UK numbers are officially 020 xxxx xxxx but many (most ) use 020x xxx xxxx What does your library use and which 50% of people do you want to annoy.

Comment: @Mark I did have that in mind (hence the word "usually" in the second paragraph), it is indeed an extra complication. Certainly using the official one for each region is still a step up from using a completely arbitrary one that's the same for all regions, though.

Comment: Yes - this is an excellent answer. This correctly notes that each country has a different International format, e.g. UK `+44 7890 XXXXXX`, Belgium  `+32 491 XX XX XX` and US : `+1 650-XXX-XXXX`. i.e. it's different for every single country

Comment: Also worthy of note that *no* spacing or separators is absolutely the hardest to read if you're used to having it in sections. +1

Comment: Worth adding that the OLD North American standard of (999) 999-9999 used parenthesis to emphasize that the 3-digit area code was for direct-dialed long distance only, and was to be omitted for local calls. Where 10-digit dialing is in force, which is now most of the continent, numbers should be expressed as 999-999-9999 to emphasize that the 3-digit area code is ***required*** for both long distance and local calls.

Comment: @Muzer +1 Look at these phone numbers: 0800 22 33 321, versus 0800 22 3 33 21, versus 0800 223 321 - imho, the first one is easier to remember, the others have awful alterations. So, it is very dependend on the number itself.

Comment: @rexkogitans it's not about the number itself most of the time but really what people are used to. In France it would be 0 800 223 332, spelt "zero, eight hundred, two hundred and twenty-three, three hundred and thirty-two". Change the grouping and the spelling gets completely different! Normal phone numbers (not 0 800) are always grouped by two: 06 48 62 26 69, or +33 6 48 62 26 69. You can get an idea there: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Num%C3%A9ro_de_t%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone#Les_structures_des_num.C3.A9ros_de_t.C3.A9l.C3.A9phone_par_pays_.28de_A_.C3.A0_Z.29

Comment: @Shautieh that's exactly what I meant - change the spelling and it changes the rhythm. The rhythm can render the phone number more or less easy to remember.

Comment: Shouldn't the user be allowed to insert whitespace wherever s/he wants? It ought to be something that can be ignored by the computer.

Comment: @nigel222 but many people won't, or will do it inconsistently.

Comment: @Muzer it doesn't matter whether the user is consistent. It's the work of nanoseconds to take a string and delete the whitespace characters. Then do whatever with the spaceless string. Keep the user's original input as a matter of politeness for when it is displayed back to him, or give him a "sanitized" version if the cost of the extra space in the DB really matters.

Comment: @Muzer but whatever else, do not turn "01912 345678" into "0 19 12 34 56 78" or "191-234 5678" etc  on an international site. That amounts to rudeness.

Comment: @nigel222 point 1) I was assuming this was some sort of phone book app, or where generally there might be multiple telephone numbers listed. It would look very unprofessional and ugly if some of them had spaces in and some of them didn't; even if the user put them there - moreover, a user is likely to enter a number without spaces but expect to see it displayed in a nicer format. Point 2) Completely agree, that was the whole point of my answer! Numbers should be converted to the standard format for the region from which the number originates (as the given library does).

Comment: My council of perfection would be to keep the user's input, and to show him his numbers as he typed them. Show other users or staff the sanitized version, which could be generated on the fly or stored in another field. But my only complete hate is being prevented from typing or submitting  the spaces which let me confirm that what I typed is correct! Post-submission, if they vanish, so be it.

Comment: @nigel222 oh, absolutely, when you're *typing* the phone number the user's input shouldn't be modified (but many users won't type spaces because of experience with badly-coded sites that don't accept them). When they're displayed later I feel they should be normalised for consistency.

Comment: This is a very good answer if automatic spacing is necessary (for dynamic localization or when rendering many numbers). However, when styling numbers by hand (e.g. your own number on your static webpage or business card) I would encourage a bit more flexibility: Memorable patterns trump strict adherence to rules, even for just retyping a number into your phone,

Comment: Good question and great answer. Spacing is important. 0781234567 is both a mobile number in France and Switzerland, but in FR it's spaced 07 81 23 45 67 while in CH it's 078 123 4567 (or 078 123 45 67).

Answer (score 31):

## Use non-breaking spaces

Other answers have talked about the pros and cons of spacing and where to place the spacing. I would like to mention one more issue. If your interface is ever going to be translated to a language like Arabic or Hebrew with a right-to-left writing system, there is an issue with spaces that you need to be aware of. Take the phone number `12345678`, you may want to format it like `12 345 678`. If the right-to-left setting has been set, it could end up being displayed like this instead:

[image: "Left-to-right" and "Right-to-left with non-breaking spaces" display number as intended, whereas "right-to-left with normal spaces" displays the number in the wrong order]

As you can see, when the right-to-left direction has been set, and when normal spaces are used, the number ends up getting displayed in the wrong order. It's as if the program considers `12` a separate number from `345` and from `678`, and so displays each number separately, from right to left.

So either don't use spaces, or use non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;` in HTML, or U+00A0).

Using non-breaking spaces is a good idea **even in a left-to-right context**, because it would prevent the number from getting split up due to wrapping.

<sub>(Note that it's not enough to use CSS like `white-space: nowrap`, you have to use non-breaking spaces.)</sub>

Answer (score 10):

## According to [Miller’s Law](http://tubikstudio.com/how-human-memory-works-tips-for-ux-designers/)

> The number of objects an average person can hold in working memory is
>   about 7 +/- 2.

Considering to his research we can have:

> 10 digit format: (+1) 12345-67890
>
> 7 digit format: (+1) 123-4567
>
> 6 digit format: (+1) 123-456

**I don't see a need to break the 10 digit format with 2 hyphens/spaces as it will work well with just 1 hyphen/space.**

> (+1) 365-245-8975
>
> (+1) 36524-58975
>
> Here, the second format is better to read and dial than the first,
>   because in first format you have to read the number 3 times, and in
>   second just 2. Or **some might combine the first two (365-245) as they start dialing**.

^

> Twenty-four countries and territories share the North American
>   Numbering Plan (NANP), with a single country code. It is a closed
>   telephone numbering plan in which all telephone numbers assigned to
>   telephones consist of seven digits.
>
> The formatting convention for phone numbers is **`(NPA) NXX-XXXX`**, where
>   NPA is the **numbering plan area** code and `NXX-XXXX` is the
>   subscriber number. The prefix NXX of the subscriber number is a code
>   for the local central office, unique in the numbering plan area. The
>   place holder N stands for the digits 2 to 9, as the subscriber number
>   may not begin with the digits 0 and 1.
>
> [National conventions for writing telephone numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers#United_States.2C_Canada.2C_and_other_NANP_countries)

## Edit:

Here, I've considered only the mobile users, but thanks to [@plasmahh](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/40758/plasmahh) for bringing in landlines (in comments below) and their appearance on screen for incoming calls.

Comment: There are countries/cultures where it is not only common to distinctly group the area code, but even confusing for people if you didn't do it but group them differently. These things can be important for people to see if the call is especially expensive e.g. whether they call a mobile phone or not. Breaking these assumptions in how numbers are layed out will annoy those people that are used to their local way of writing them

Comment: @PlasmaHH Breaking the assumptions will be costly, but if the **effort is for making an experience easy**; an initiative will be worth as it is **backed by a research.**

Comment: It depends on what you want to make easy. Implementation? sure. Input? Of course. Reading and using? I don't see how an unusual arrangement that is breaking existing expectations is making anything easy in that regard. The OP is providing too little context to tell where it fits.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I think it will make Reading & Using easy.

Comment: It may be for north american numbers, but if someone would write a number in my city as +49 699 3456 instead of +49 69 93456 as it would be normally done, I bet an awful lot of people will dial 3456 instead of 93456. Similarly if someone wrote a number as +49 5118 4173 instead of +49 511 84173 people would look up what area code 5118 is supposed to be and find nothing.

Comment: @PlasmaHH My emphasis is on adding **even load on working memory** '+49 5118 4173' instead of **odd** '+49 511 84173'

Comment: if i see a dash in a phone number i presume i have landed on a US site by mistake. Unilaterally attempting to standardise something like this is a bad idea

Comment: @DPS: That doesn't help much if it is altering the information that is conveyed by the grouping by convention. If people are used to having the area code being in the first group, your way suddenly provides the information "the area code is 05118" while in fact it is 0511

Comment: @PlasmaHH I might be wrong, but in the world of Mobile Phones - how many of us really pay attention to area codes?

Comment: @DPS: It might be different where you live, but here we do. I do the majority of my phone calls from a landline to a landline, for reasons of price and convenience (e.g. my work landline has a nice headset, at home my chrome plugin can call the number directly from my computer). So do a lot of people I know. Not many people will always chose mobile over landline when they are at home/work and both is available. Btw. it may also be a matter of incoming phone calls, in a missed calls list "oh, I don't know that number from city xyz, that must be abc, he is living there"

Comment: @DPS: additionally the area code tells you if its a mobile phone or not you are going to call, which not only tells you something about the price, but the credibility of a business. If they only have a mobile number, its pretty shady.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Agree with you! I mostly considered the mobile users.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Thanks BTW! I've updated the post with a note on landlines :)

Comment: @DPS: "in the world of Mobile Phones - how many of us really pay attention to area codes?" - anyone who has to pay a different charge depending on which mobile phone network they are calling into, in countries where a couple of different area codes denote different mobile phone networks owned by different companies. And what is more - mobile phones don't generally work well within buildings over here, the 4/4 bars of signal strength I have under the open sky quickly drop to "no network" when entering some of the buildings I frequently stay in, such as the one I live in.

Comment: This is a very US centric answer

Comment: Even just looking at how memory works, it's easy to explain how this will fail on regional lines: "chunking" in memory makes use of prior knowledge (that's why we can remember "square table" as 1 item, not "square horizontal platform supported by four upright supports, approximately 3 feet high"). To a UK reader, 0127 352 3670 requires conscious memory of the individual digits, whereas the locally conventional 01273 523 670 can make use of a) knowledge that the first chunk means "Brighton"; and b) the "schema" that the remaining numbers will form an ABC ABC rhythm.

Answer (score 8):

There is an ITU-T Recommendation [E.123](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-E.123-200102-I/en) for the presentation of telephone numbers.

> This Recommendation applies specifically to the printing of national and international telephone numbers, electronic mail addresses and Web addresses on letterheads, business cards, bills, etc. Regard has been given to the printing of existing telephone directories. The standard notation for printing telephone numbers, E-mail addresses and Web addresses helps to reduce difficulties and errors, since this address information must be entered exactly to be effective.

See also the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.123).

However the question of how to group numbers with spaces is not addressed by E.123 and is a matter of national convention (and even then often ignored).  For example UK telephone numbers are conventionally grouped `07xxx yyy zzz` but some people group them `07xx xyy yzzz`.

Comment: Could you expand the answer by quoting/describing more about E.123?

Comment: Unless I'm missing a large part of it, this standard seems to define *what* punctuation to use (spaces, parentheses in specific circumstances) but not *where* to use it (how many spaces? where should they be put?).

Comment: @IMSoP AIUI, the placing of spaces is a matter of national convention.  What E.123 tells for (for example) is things like not mixing national and international syntax at the same time.

Comment: @Alnitak Right, but since spacing was one of the two things the OP asked about, I just thought I'd clarify that this doesn't directly answer that part of the question.

Answer (score 6):

I believe there cannot be a single format here, since it may vary depending on the country. For example, in India, mobile phone numbers are 10 digit. It may be represented as 3-3-4. A good format, in my view, will be how you might verbally communicate a phone number which is usually in chunks of 3 or 4 digits. This will increase retention otherwise the user will have to put in cognitive effort to break a larger number into smaller chunks.

Answer (score 5):

The second half of your question (spacing) seems to be well covered by other answers, so I'll address the first half:

> Country code:
>
> +393401234xxx
>
> or
>
> 00393401234xxx
>
> The first example I think is more legible, but perhaps not
>   understandable for those who do not have the proper familiarity with
>   the phone.

This is not solely a readability factor. It's also a localization issue. The first format, is valid everywhere: the `+` symbol means "dial the international prefix". The second format, means exactly what it says, "dial 00". Whether or not that is the correct international prefix depends on what country you're dialing out from. While `00` is correct for *most* countries, there are [plenty of countries that use something different](http://wikitravel.org/en/International_dialling_prefix).

So, which format you use depends on whether or not you care about displaying the correct telephone number to users from countries that do not use `00` as the international prefix.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the best way to display a phone number is preserving exactly the way **I** have entered it. Do not try to change it to a uniform standard.

- There can be unusual patterns in numbers that make them easier to remember or recognize e.g. `1 22 333` becomes worse if you format it as `12 23 33`.
- "Standard" formats were created in the era of landlines and number routing tied to physical switches, so are based around concepts of city/area and network provider codes. In the era of mobile phones and number portability between operators most of it stopped making any sense.
- It's a massive localization challenge that can backfire if done incorrectly. Be careful not to force US-centric formatting on users outside US. This could not only hinder readability of numbers from around the world, but also make your product appear ignorant.

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about form entry. This about how to present a number to the user.

Comment: @plainclothes The advice can still stand if the number is being entered somewhere else in the system - let whoever types in the number decide how to display it.

Comment: @IMSoP The organization should still have a pattern for their own *display* of the number. This isn't about entry of any kind.

Comment: @plainclothes What organization? How do you know it's "not about entry of any kind"? I understand how you're interpreting the question, but I don't see why you're so sure, because the wording of the question seems quite broad and ambiguous to me.

Comment: Just interpreting the question: *"What is the best way to write a phone number? … The first example I think is more legible …"* Users aren't concerned with the *best* or *most legible* format. This is a question of the right format for presentation to users / customers.

Comment: "In the era of mobile phones and number portability between operators most of it stopped making any sense." - this may be different by country, but in some places, most of it makes as much sense as for landlines. For instance, the prefix that used to be an area code may be used as a network code in mobile networks, so it is just as useful to have that one visually separated from the rest. And even though number portability might exist as an option, the fees one has to pay for that can make enough users opt against it, thus making the prefix still a pretty good heuristic.

Comment: *"Be careful not to force US-centric formatting on users outside US."* Like how when I call some people in the US who have call screening and am prompted to "please enter your ten-digit telephone number now". As luck would have it my home landline phone number *can* be crammed into ten digits, but my cell phone number or my work phone number cannot be. And of course it shows up all weird to the callee.

Answer (score 2):

### Respect regional expectations

As the answers here indicate, there are a lot of local variations. You'll generally be able to find the regionally appropriate arrangement with a survey of common use.

Users are accustomed to remembering certain types of things (e.g. phone numbers) in certain patterns. Respect the patterns and users will thank you.

### The bigger issue

Fortunately, very few of us have to commit numbers to memory now. We have access to the World's information on our phone. Search for the person or company you want to call, and just tap the number — it's magic! ✨

IOW, in today's world …

## The most important thing about your number is that no one should have to remember it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can follow the recommendation from [Google Developers, Web fundaments](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/click-to-call/):

> Use the international dialing format
>
> Always supply the phone number using the international dialing format:
>   the plus sign (+), country code, area code, and number. While not
>   absolutely necessary, it’s a good idea to separate each segment of the
>   number with a hyphen (-) for easier reading and better auto-detection.
>
> Using a hyphenated international dialing format ensures that no matter
>   where the user is calling from, whether a few hundred meters away or
>   thousands of kilometers, their call will be connected.
>   [image]

Also, you can see that the default format in popular frameworks like Angular material is: (###) ###-####

[image]

Comment: This is one thing that Google have got wrong in their UI guidelines.  The use of a dash as grouping separator is unusual in many parts of the world (e.g. most of Europe) and will just serve to annoy.  Mandating it as a good idea for all numbers is simply idiotic.

Answer (score 1):

> The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose
>   from.  -- Andrew Tanenbaum

I think that promoting a single standard, even if not well-known in certain locales, might be helpful in the long run to get more people to understand and expect this format.

Others have also pointed to the [E.123 international notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.123), e.g. **+22 607 123 4567**.

However, I have found the Microsoft Canonical format (see same E.123 article as it is derived from it) slightly more helpful when not needing the country code (for internal dialling), e.g. **+22 (607) 123 4567**.

That said, personally I haven't used a manual land-line telephone in *years* (either dial or buttons). The numbers in my Android phone book are displayed with dashes instead of spaces of the E.123 if not stored with formatting, and storing them with the international dialling code does not make any difference when calling them on the mobile network.

Comment: "see same E.123 article as it is derived from it" is ambiguous and I read it as suggesting that E.123 is derived from Microsoft's, when it's the other way around. Anyway, "I think that promoting a single standard ... might be helpful" and "Others have also pointed to ... However, I have found" seem like a contradiction. Promoting a single standard also means following a single standard if one already exists rather than choosing your own different standard.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

> +country_code(operator)xxx-xx-xx

For example, Ukrainian numbers are often spelled in this way:

> +380(95)123-12-12

Comment: It would be good to provide an actual example of this format, just so we know this is taken from an existing reference since you haven't provided any specific explanation of why this is a user friendly format except it is used in Ukraine, so it might only be a good solution for certain countries.

Comment: @MichaelLai I am not sure I can provide a formal specification straightway, but that is just what I know from my personal experience. Also, the OP mentioned "personally using ...", so I thought they expected just an advice based rather on personal feeling of readability than some kind of a formally defined standard.

Comment: Oh, I am not asking for a formal specification, but was wondering if there is an actual example you can show because I suspect this was part of the reason for the down vote (not by me). But I think if you can provide more explanation or example then it would attract upvotes.

Comment: @MichaelLai I've already added a comment to the question with a link to a lot of example formats recognized by IE11 grouped by country, let them choose what they like the best if any.

Answer (score 0):

Most situations,user should not need to know number's country code. I suggest cancel country code instead of grouping the phone numbers with countries.

Comment: I suggest posting some comments to the person who has asked the question so you can get a better understanding of the situation. Even though you are making the assumption that most situations will not require knowledge of the country code, this might not be the case in this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't explain what is the use for this phone number, and why this format is needed. There can be several different user cases, in which case there isn't a single "one size fits all" answer.

## Static Number

In this scenario, OP just needs to add a phone number somewhere. This is very simple, and many answers above covers this case. The only caveat is **localization** : is the site targeted to an international audience within a country , a regional audience or a local one? In the first case, we'll need international code, in the second case, only area code and in the final case local code may be enough. This way, we avoid unnecessary cognitive load, improve recognition and ability to remember the number, making it easier for the user to dial the number as well.

Please note **this is specially true in media**: if the number is meant to be used on a site or app, yu'll probably need international codes since the audience you'll reach will be wider, UNLESS you want to restrict access to a single country. If you're using this in magazines, you'll probably leave out international code, using only area code. Finally, on a billboard you won't use any area code, just local number.

## Dynamic Number

In this case, the number will be added by different (unknown) users and we need to define an input format. First thing we need to know is what I mention above. For example, if the number the user will input is always inside a country, it's useless and confusing to ask for international code. Additionally, there are libraries that automatically prefill country code based on geo detection or country input from a previous field. This is a recommended way so you don't have to worry about users using `0` or `+` for international code.

Once you define this is to let the user **type the number the way they would dial it on their phones**. Hence, no spaces or dashes, only numbers.

## The masking scenario

The most common problem with dynamic numbers is that some developers feel the urge to mask inputs so they look nicer (which they do). However, this is very problematic and should be used only to restrict numbers. Alas, this will never work for international numbers (see answers and comments in this page about the many diiferent possible formats) and you'll need to be incredibly sure about the numbering system. A quick example: my city code is `011`. My parents city code is `02477`. Imagine trying to mask this. And we're talking inside the same country!

## In short

The key for the answer is **localization**, and based on this, whichever format feels more natural for users.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself 1 question, are you going to be dealing with more than just your nations' phone numbers?

In the UK (where I am from) I would expect a layout as 00000 000000 or 00000 000 000 depending on landline or mobile, respectively (though the former is still valid for a mobile)

America has (000) 000 000 (can't remember the exact layout) as a potential calling system, which wouldn't work for British numbers.

Then you have to question whether you will go with terrestrial numbers (e.g. 00000 000000) or international (+440000 000000). If you already take the user's country, I would personally recommend the terrestrial number, as most people will remember that, and you can work out the international dialling code from that.

Comment: My UK number is 020 8xxx xxxx... like all London numbers plus many would incorrectly quote that as 0208 xxx xxxx

Answer (score -5):

When presenting large set of data or digits, you might want to "[chunk](http://dwb4.unl.edu/Diss/Cooper/UNSW.htm)" your information. Personally I think the easiest to remember is to present your phone number in sets of 4 digits. Ideally country/area code follow by the phone number:

**+65 1234 5678**

I choose "+" instead of parentheses so that user could click on the number to start dialling immediately.

Comment: Your example can't be internationally applied. Singapore numbers are inherently split to 4-digit groups whereas others not, so applying your format to, say, Ukrainian number, you'll end up having operator code and first two digits of the number itself in the first chunk which is illogical.